# Will I need to buy a new mobile phone (some french phone) if I move to france and intend to use SIM card of that country?

Tags: france, cellphones

I am from India. i will be moving to France in September for about 3 years for PhD. I need to buy a new phone anyways.

Should I go to France and buy a new phone there since SIM card of France won't work in mobile phones of Samsung, Sony or Moto or I can buy any phone I want and SIM cards that are made are of standard sizes internationally?

Comment: Since this is about a long-term stay, it should be on Expatriates.SE.

Comment: SIM cards are standard and it's possible to use a GSM phone from abroad in France (provided it supports the right standard and frequencies and is unlocked) but there are a couple of other factors to take into account. (1) If you buy a phone just before leaving, you are liable to pay VAT on it when moving to France. (2) If you intend to take a monthly plan (as opposed to pay-as-you-go or other flexible options) and commit for a year or two, you can get heavy discount on the price of the phone. So it would seem much simpler to obtain your new phone in France.

Comment: Flagged for migration to Expats.

Answer (score 2):

SIM cards are an international standard. France uses [the GSM network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_network_operators_of_Europe#France). Therefore, all you will need is a GSM headset that work on 800/900/1800/2100/2600 frequencies and is unlocked and you can use it in France.